# Distance measure between two sequences of different lengths

Tags: distance, distance-functions, sequential-pattern-mining

I am looking for some distance (or similarity) measure between two sequences, possibly of different lengths. Conceptually, I would like a measure with a property that $[3,1,5]$ is similar to $[3,1,4,5]$ (just one insertion), and $d([1,2,3], [1,2,4]) < d([1,2,3], [1,2,99])$ because 3 is closer to 4 than to 99. I do not any more specific properties in my mind.

I thought of the Levenstein distance first, but its property that substitution between any two values is constant is not what I desire. I also thought of the Manhattan distance but it does not allow, as far as I know, the sequences have different lengths.

I admit this is a crude description of what I intend, but I do not have much more specific requirement for now. It will be great if you could point out some functions to measure the distance between sequences of different lengths.
Just a link to a paper or websites would also be helpful.

Comment: It sounds like [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) is what you are interested in. Take a look at our [tag:dynamic-time-warping] tag.

Comment: Dynamic time warping looks very promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Stephan Kolassa commented, the dynamic time warping is promising in this case.